# Проверить скрыт ли элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно проверить, скрыт ли элемент

Вот код:

```
$(function() {
if($('#id').is(':hidden')){ alert('Hidden'); }
});
```

Работает, но как проверить так же на `visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;` обёртываемый блок с `display:none` и прочие способы скрытия элемента с экрана?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function check(selector) {
  var cs = [ 'display', 'visibility', 'opacity' ];
  var rc= [];

  for (var i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
    rc.push($(selector).css(cs[i]));
  }

  return rc;
}

check('#foo');
```

при вызове функции передаете селектор который нужно проверить, массив cs - что нужно проверить, массив rc - результат, ну а дальше уже условие вставляете под вашу задачу

Comment: проще не массив возвращать, а true/false

Comment: Вы сути вопроса видимо не поняли.

Comment: Что не так? Идет проверка на display, visibility, opacity, поставить необходимые условия я думаю не является проблемой, как и получить возвращаемый массив с true/false. Проверка через .is на visibility и opacity невозможна, поскольку элемент визуально занимает место в теле документа.